# What is the meaning of this joke?

Tags: meaning, puns

In the video game Tingle's Love Balloon Trip, whose plot is a parody of *The Wizard of Oz*, there is a scene in which Kakashi, the scarecrow boy, says goodbye to a friend. The following dialog takes place between Kakashi and his friend:

> Kakashi: ぼく そろそろ いくね。
>
> K's friend: むう、 たびだつんか。ちょっぴり さみしいのぅ ・・・。
>
> Kakashi: また あえるよ ! だって ぼく ワラだもん !!
>
> K's friend: ? そ、 そうか ・・・たっしゃでな、 カカシくん。

As far as I understand, Kakashi's second line means, "We can meet again! After all, I'm (made of) straw!!" Of course, Kakashi is actually made of straw, being a scarecrow. But taken literally this doesn't make much sense - how is that going to help him meet his friend again?

Maybe it has something to with the ワラ reading of the Kanji 笑, referring to laughter?

I guess this is some sort of wordplay, but what does it mean?

Comment: お友達も、カカシのジョークの意味がわからず、困惑しているようです（？　そ、そうか…）。多分、意図的な「ジョークのようで、意味が分からない文」なんだと思います。敢えてジョークに分類するなら[すべり芸](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8A%E8%8A%B8)の一種かも。

Comment: I guess Kakashi said I am around every corner because I am straw. Absolutely it's my guess.

Comment: "The cheerful scarecrow is mentally lacking and is in search for intelligence." Also, *perhaps* an obscure reference to 座敷童子 (ざしき**わら**し) 「旧家に**時折現れる**といわれる家の守り神」 Well, probably not, I guess... (The scarecrow in Zelda Oot appears throughout Hyrule, perhaps also a reference to this...)

Comment: I give it some thought everytime this thread gets bumped to the top, but I still do not think this is a joke or wordplay.  It is not funny at all (and I am a Japanese speaker).

Comment: @l'électeur I guess you're right. I assumed it was a joke because the setup/timing of the scene seemed comical, but I may have been wrong.

Comment: By the way, what do I do with a question I don't expect to have a satisfying answer any more?

Comment: If you want to force wordplay out of it, one could maybe take ワラ=我ら to make him mean something like "I am us," though I'm not suggesting this is likely (or amusing).

Comment: @waldrumpus If you don't think it's answerable, then we can close it.  (The main effect of closing is to prevent answers from being posted.) I've gone ahead and closed it, but we can still reopen it if that's what people want.

Answer (score 2):

I think what Kakashi meant was that since he is made of straw, he can be found anywhere, thus they will meet one way or the other.